# How can I publish my thesis?

Tags: publications, thesis, research-undergraduate

I have a written thesis, as my Final year project. I have submitted in university.

but now i want to make it professionally mine.

I want to publish it some where but i don't have such kind of experience before. I am total Rookie in this field.

Any Expert Opinion?

**Note:** Thesis in About "Handwriting Recognition "

Comment: The most directly useful expert opinion will come from your advisor.

Comment: But I am no more in my Under-graduate University. I am 200 km away from that one for my Post Graduation. and I cant Trust new people here. and obviously i cant connect to advisor again and again. He is a teacher and have own stuff to do.

Comment: I don't see a problem with sending an email to your former advisor with a brief question like this. The most important issue is whether your thesis is of sufficient quality and originality to be publishable - not to discourage you, but most undergraduate theses are not. Your advisor is probably the best judge of that.

Comment: And what do you mean that you can't trust people at your new institution? What are your concerns? (You'd trust random internet strangers more?)

Comment: sounds better. but Here i am not giving my thesis. and m Graduate In Information Technology, so i know about Authentic websites. I am not going to put my thesis any where. And also it already on Turnitin.com with my name. 
Problem is i don't know the procedure.

Comment: What kind of publication do you have in mind? Technical article? Book with esteemed publisher? Vanity press?

Comment: My thesis worth to be publish. I have a novel research in it about Handwriting Recognition. I gave internal and External Viva of that. and Every teacher Appreciated it and suggest me to publish in journal.

Comment: @DaveClarke as i Mentioned i m rookie in this field. so i dont know what is best way. can you tell me please?

Answer (score 2):

1. **Publishing the thesis "as is"**

Your first option to to publish the thesis as it is now, without any modifications. This is usually the easier thing to do. Assuming your thesis in in PDF format, you can just upload it to your own website. Another option would be to upload it to a repository such as [figshare.com](http://figshare.com/), where it will also be assigned a DOI and it will be easier for people to cite (and discover?).

2. **Making a journal article out of it**

This option will be harder, but will also probably benefit you much more. I'm assuming that you know how a journal article looks like, so now your job is to make it look like one. The technical aspects may be challenging at first, but they are pretty straightforward. Every journal has a "guide for authors" section where they instruct you exactly how and where to submit the article. What format to use, how to draft the figures, what citation format to use, etc. If you are not sure which journal to publish to, I suggest that you look on the citation list of your own thesis and see which journals published articles similar to yours. One of the reasons that this option is harder is because you have to convince the editors and reviewers of the journal that the article is novel, important, well written and worth publishing. The article will be subject to peer review which will require additional time and effort from your side. It is a lengthy process and can take several months.

Comment: I dont have website. but i found from your answer journal is better option. i can make changes in it to fit in to journal. but obviously i want to take more benefit. as mentioned "I am rookie in field" so i dont know how journals look like. but if you suggest me some stuff. i will make it according to that.

Comment: Didn't you read some published literature as a part of your thesis writing process?

Comment: read. but that was research papers. and my thesis is 60+ pages. 
should i convert it to research paper ? of 5-6 pages ? is it would be better approach?

Comment: Ok. Research papers are published in journals. Now, I don't know your field and what is the typical paper length, but in my field papers of 20-25 pages are common. For a research paper you would like only the important findings, not everything. I don't see how it would not be possible.

Comment: From where i can get this type of information? like paper   length, etc?

Comment: It's in the answer. Each journal has a guide to authors. Also, read through some of the journal's articles to see how they look like.